# How to display entire list based off of lookup?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

I have a list of project ID's. Each project ID has multiple app ID's.  I need to create a form that list each app id as a field name so the user can submit allocation to each app id on the project level.

Currently, I have a list that has every app on a single row making it difficult to add up the distribution.  There are many projects and many applications that will be filled out so ideally, I would like to create a form that can open one project and display all the app ID's and also allow the user to fill in the allocation. Is this possible?

EX:

```
Project ID  -  App ID  -  Allocation
1                A         50
1                B         50
2                C         33
2                D         33
2                E         33
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is not a relational database, so this is a bit of a mission, but it can be done. Mark Rackley has a great video tutorial for such a scenario for 2013 and the page contains a link to tutorials for earlier versions.

http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26

Quoting:

> So, for those who care more about the “what” than the “how”, the steps
>   we will be taking are:
>
> 1. Create Lists and Document Library for scripts
> 2. Add the Child list to the Parent item display form and create a web
>      part connection to only display the appropriate child items
> 3. Create script for the Parent’s display form and add script to the
>      display form page
> 4. Create script for the Child’s new form and add script to the new
>      form page.